# Apache Ant: Is it possible to insert/replace with text from a raw text file?

Tags: apache, ant, insert, replace

I'd like to take text from a standard text file and insert it into an XML that is copied with replace tokens by Apache Ant. Is this possible?

Example (this is what I use so far):

```
<macrodef name="generateUpdateFile">
    <sequential>
        <echo message="Generating update file ..." level="info"/>
        <copy file="update.xml" tofile="${path.pub}/update.xml" overwrite="true">
            <filterchain>
                <replacetokens>
                    <token key="app_version" value="${app.version}"/>
                    <token key="app_updatenotes" value="${app.updatenotes}"/>
                </replacetokens>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The ${app.updatenotes} are currently a string that is defined in a build.properties file. But instead I'd like to write update notes in a simple text file and take them from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The apache ant [loadfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task will allow to read your text file, and put its content into the `app.updatenotes` property.

You can simply use:

```
<loadresource property="app.updatenotes">
   <file file="notes.txt"/>
</loadresource>
```

Then, use your `filterchain`, just as before.
`loadresource` has some options, for instance to control the encoding of your file, or to control how to react if the file is not present, or not readable.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the hint tonio!